# Substrate Deployment for Prod/Staging

Tags: substrate-node-template, nodes, genesis, substrate-node

I am wondering where do you deploy your substrate nodes for production or staging? Do you deploy the nodes to some cloud servers? How many connected nodes are sufficient to keep the network running?

Answer (score 1):

We deployed our public nodes on GCP(2C 6G).

Three nodes are enough for us. It can afford subquery and subscan indexing.

---

For production, we only deployed two bootnodes. And we left other seats for the community.

Comment: appreciate the insight!